# Storyboard UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I am trying to build an application for iphone with using storyboard that starting with login screen and after user touch the login button, it should check it with authentication method. But, i could not directly link the login button to UITabBarController, because when user touch the button it directly goes the Tab Bar page without checking the login method. And also i tried to create mytabBar class it extends from  UITabBarController and I set UITabBarController in custom classs as mytabBar in storyboard. Then I putted in my login view controller class;

```
#import "tabBar.h" 
- (IBAction)loginCheck:(id)sender{

    tabBar *tabbar = [[tabBar alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:tabbar animated:YES];
}
```

but it still does not working.

Comment: I mean it works but it creates new UITabBarController, it does not go to the the tab bar that i created in xcode interface builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type is `tabBar`? There is no `check` in this method. Maybe do:

```
//...
NSLog(@"Log");
//...
```

... in the method to be sure it gets called.

Whenever you are working with `UIStoryboard` you are doing something like this instead of initializing a new instance of `tabBar`:

```
- (void)showModalAssistantViewController
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]; //Put your right Storyboard Name here
tabBar *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"]; //Put your right identifier here
[viewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[viewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

... The identifier can be found in the `ViewController's` Inspector-Tab in IB.